# Failure to deploy on IBM Web Aplication Server 8.5 using jenkins

Tags: jenkins, websphere, jmx, mbeans

We've been configuring an automated deployment using WebSphere Deployer Plugin v 1.3.4 for IBM WAS 8.5. 
We have finished all the pipeline and checked the conecction to SOAP, all works right, but we have one last problem, jenkins throws this failure:

[Jenkins Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2Q32.png)

```
Generating EAR For Artifact: xxxxxxxxxx
Error deploying to IBM WebSphere Application Server: org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere.services.deployment.DeploymentServiceException: Could not determine if artifact 'xxxxxxxxxx' is installed: ADMA0089E: The AppManagement MBean is not found.
```

We have researched a lot, but we can determine which is the problem?

Note: We configure the Generic JVM arguments with the IBM suport, these are the arguments we added:

[Generic JVM arguments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFk50.png)

```
-Dcom.ibm.team.server.monitoring.mbean.server=WebSphere
-Djavax.management.builder.initial= 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10033 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. Websphere Deployer Plugin requires Oracle or Open JDK (no longer support's IBM's J9 JRE) when running under Jenkins. Generic JVM arguments are not required for the WDP plugin. Lastly, you can check issues.jenkins-ci.org and search for fixes that others have found regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check WebSphere Connectivity Port setting  in Jenkins, it should be SOAP port of Deployment Manager(default: 8879), not SOAP port of Websphere Application Server.

Comment: True, but if it's just a standalone instance of Websphere and not WebSphere ND. You just point it to the SOAP port (typically 8880)